# BeginInvoke() giving errors in my C# code

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to implement **BeginInvoke()** in my code and came across this part which is throwing error.

```
 private void ShowPicLensPlot()
        {
            if (PicLensPlot.InvokeRequired)
            {
                PicLensPlot.BeginInvoke(new Action<Control, bool>(ShowPicLensPlot, PicLensPlot, true));
            }
            else
            {
                PicLensPlot.BringToFront();
            }
        }
```

The error is **MethodName Expected**
The above source code has been converted to C# from VB and the online tool was used to to this.
**PicLensPlot** is a  **private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox PicLensPlot;**

Comment: Yes this is wrong. What do you want to happen? And why is this tagged both WPF and WinForms? They act differently.

Comment: removed WPF. Its a Winform app. how to get this issue fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
if (PicLensPlot.InvokeRequired)
{
    PicLensPlot.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ShowPicLensPlot()));
}
else
{
    PicLensPlot.BringToFront();
}
```

Comment: This works . I have tried it but just wanted to know why my code is not working and what does Action<Control,bool> is there for ?

Comment: BeginInvoke has an overload where you can pass arguments to the action delegate. It would however not make sense here because the ShowPicLensPlot method doesn't have a bool argument.